# How to squeeze block in bottom of parent block?

Tags: html, css

I have `div` block, that should be displayed on full page by width and height.

Inside this block I have another `div` with position fixed:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   top:0;
   background:green
}

.child {
  position:fixed;
  botttom:0px;
  height:80px;
  width:100%
  background:yellow;
}
```

Problem is that `parent` block is not displayed on the full page, and intern block `.child` is not located at the bottom of `parent` block.

Comment: `position: fixed` element relate to the viewport, not to any element parent

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: It means no matter where you put it in the markup, it will always position itself relative to the viewport, so if you give it left/top 0, it will always stay at upper left corner

Comment: You also have two typo's, where you missed the end semicolon `;` at `width: 100%` and to many `t` at `botttom:0px;`

Comment: So, as I got it right, I dont need to use fixed?

Comment: If you want the `child` to always be at the bottom of the `parent`, don't use `fixed`, use `absolute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```html
<style>
.parent {
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   top:0;
   background:green;
   width:100%;
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  height:80px;
  width: 100%;
  background:yellow;
}
</style>

<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP's code work, though it had a typo, and we don't post answers for typo's, we comment and/or flag them ... and maybe even worse, how does that help to only _Try this code_ ... next time, add a decent explanation